# For What $a$ The Linear Equations Have Sloutions

Tags: linear-algebra

$2x+ay-z=-2$

$x-3z=-3$

$x+2y+az=-1$

I have thought about reducing a matrix so in the end I will have an equation with $a$ then I can determine for which $a$ the are one solution/infinite solutions/no solution, but it does not seems to work
I have row reduced the matrix and got
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 3-a & 4 \\
0 & a-4 & -a-1& -1 
\end{array}\right)$$

the solutions are for one solution: $a=5$,$a\neq 2$  no solution for: $a=-5,a=2$

Comment: The equations have a solution if the determinant of the left $3\times3$ part of that matrix is non-zero. In your reduced matrix, the determinant is most readily computed by expansion along the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Row Reduced Form as:

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{a+3}{2} & 1 \\
0 & a-5 & \frac{-5(a+1)}{2} & -1 \end{array} \right)$

So the determinant comes as $(-3a+10-a^2)$

For no solution, determinant is zero, so, $(-3a+10-a^2)=0$

$\Rightarrow a=-5, a=2$

Comment: Dear @Diya, You are correct. So, your final answer is $a\neq -5$ and $a\neq 2$. However, note that your question is "For what value(s) of $a$ does the system of linear equations have solutions?" So, you have two cases: (i) Unique Solution (ii) Infinitely Many Solutions. In general, the determinant approach is useful for case (i) and for a "square system". A good option is to use elementary row operations. You can perform one last elementary row operation to the matrix you got: $-(a-5)R_{2}+R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}$.

Comment: Thank you!! I was stuck wondering what the last operation can be and didn't think to use $a$ itself to get it. *facepalm* OP mentioned the answers for no solution too, so I explained how I got that. :)

Comment: You will get the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{a+3}{2} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} (5-a) (a+3)-\frac{5 (a+1)}{2} & 4-a \end{array} \right)$. So, for a unique solution $\frac{1}{2} (5-a) (a+3)-\frac{5 (a+1)}{2}\neq 0$ (this will give $a\neq -5$ and $a\neq 2$). For infinitely many solutions $\frac{1}{2} (5-a) (a+3)-\frac{5 (a+1)}{2}=0$ AND $4-a=0$. There no $a$ values that satisfy both the equations. So, it turns out the system cannot have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Dear @Diya, I actually thought you were the one who posted the question :-). My mistake.

Comment: Lol that's fine, I'm here to learn too. :)

Comment: @Diya what elementary row operations you used?

Comment: Beginning with $\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -3 & -3 \\
2 & a & -1 & -2 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: subtracting first row from second row and twice the first row from third row to get: $\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & -2 & -3-a & -2 \\
0 & a-4 & -1-2a & 0 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Dividing second row by $(-2)$ to get: $\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{a+3}{2} & 1 \\
0 & a-4 & -1-2a & 0 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Subtracting second row from third row to get: $\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & a & -1 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{a+3}{2} & 1 \\
0 & a-5 & \frac{-5(a+1)}{2}  & -1 \end{array} \right)$ and then I found the determinant.

Comment: I am trying to solve it before "Subtracting second row from third row to get" by $-(a-4)R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3$ and what I just is $(a+2)(a-1)=0$ so $a=-2$ or $a=1$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute the 2nd equation in the other two to get ay+5z=4 and 2y+(a+3)z=2. Take 2 x first - a x second to get $z=\frac{2(a-4)}{(a+5)(a-2)}$. If $a\ne 2\text{ or} -5$ then this gives a unique solution for x,y,z. If a=2, then the two equations above become 2y+5z=4 and 2y+5z=2, which is impossible. Similarly, if a=-5 they become y-z=-4/5 and 1, which is impossible.